# Is there a way to prevent iOS from asking user permission every time my app tries to delete a photo?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing an app to help the user organize/clean their photo library in iOS. The problem I'm having is that, even though I have requested and been granted permission to use the photo library, *deletions* trigger a permission request to the user *every time*.

The following code:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges(
                { PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets([asset] as NSArray) },
                completionHandler: { (success,error) in ...
```

gives me a popup like this:

[image]

Even though I click "Delete", and even though, in Settings, the app has access to the photo library, I get this popup every time the app tries to delete a photo.

Is there a way to avoid this, or will I need to just queue up a list of assets to delete and delete them all in one operation (or will even *that* ask the user to approve each deletion)?

Comment: You do not own the photo

Comment: looks like you're going to have to delete a list of photos with a single approval - have you seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377872/only-one-ios-permission-dialog-when-modifying-multiple-photos ?

Comment: Good find. Thanks!